# Is it possible to combine two CFU455IT +/-2kHz (4kHz) ceramic filters to get a +/-1.25kHz bandwith (2.5kHz) filter?

Tags: rf, filter, passive-networks, receiver, piezo

Can I put two of these cheap (less than 3USD) and common CFU455IT +/-2kHz (4kHz bandwith -6dB ) ceramic filters in series to get a lower bandwidth good for SSB TX? If I'm correct I will get -12dB at +/-2kHz so the bandwidth will be reduced a bit, I can trim the rest by adding a trimmer in parallel to the filters and playing with the loading resistor. What about CFU455HT? They are even more easy to get and cost 1.25USD. It sure beats paying 50USD for a factory made one and I have only so much crystals to put in filters.

When making an SSB superhet RX are lightly loaded (100k ohms) LC resonant circuits and RC lowpass audio filters good on their own or do I really need that filter?

73 de SO9LEK

[image: filter datasheet]

Comment: No, with no further components

Comment: What further components are needed?

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, but no.

Well, you kind of can, but you really can't:

When you just put two resonant filters in series, like these ceramic filters, you do, in fact, get a sharper resonance in passband; will it have a  2.5 kHz wide 3dB-bandwidth? Only with extreme luck; your datasheet doesn't specify.

It's a technique actually used with crystal resonators, usually, in the form of *ladder filters*, but when you build these, you'd typically be very careful to select resonators that are very well-matched; otherwise, you'd be running the risk of strong insertion loss, or generally surprising passband shape.

## What to do instead

Think about it this way:

It might simply not be worth it building an analog bandpass filter, as you'd never need that. Which system of yours *really* requires a 2.5 kHz bandwidth on a 455 kHz IF?

The fact alone that you're planning to work on a 455 kHz band shows you've thought about filtering architecture: That's a classical intermediate frequency, for which narrow filters are available – and with narrow, we mean "ratio of bandwidth to center frequency is small"; it's, due to pure physics, way harder to build a 5 kHz filter around 1 GHz than around 455 kHz.

### Superhet, active filters

So, if you really need less bandwidth, the "natural" way would be to add another superhet stage to go to an even lower IF, say, 8 kHz (or really anything above 2.5 kHz, I just materialized that number out of thin air) and look into *active multi-stage filters*; Analog Devices has an excellent [Filter Design Wizard](https://tools.analog.com/en/filterwizard/) that takes you through all the design steps and delivers a design, BOM, curves including error margins.

### Unless masochistic, don't do analog filters

Then, again, I'd personally really *not* do that, for 99.95% of use cases.

You've got a 4 kHz wide passband around 455 kHz after one stage of filtering. Because I'm lazy with the arithmetic, let's say that's 5 kHz bandwidth that you'd have to deal with.

So, with a microcontroller including an ADC that can do 800 thousand samples per second (or more), you'd be *oversampling*¹ by a factor of ; that means you gain 80/4 = 20 bits in ADC resolution. At which point even a terribly performing 10 bit ADC absolutely suffices to reconstruct even the weakest signal out of noise, and possible interferer within the 1.5 kHz bandwidth you wanted to cut off with your second ceramic filter.

All you'd need is

- a microcontroller, ideally one that includes
- an ADC, as well as,
- an ADC buffer (i.e. a unity-gain amplifier, just so that the ADC's input impedance doesn't affect the upstream analog signal chaing; typically, you want this, but if you've already got an IF amplifier, potentially not necessary),
- as well as a bit of firmware code that

  - sets up the ADC,
  - configures some DMA transfers to get the memory from the ADC when a conversion is done automatically,
  - sets up a timer so that ADC conversion is done every \$\frac{1}{800\,\text{kHz}\$ automatically, and
  - processes the resulting digital signal.

Such microcontrollers ([example](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATSAME53J20A)) aren't cheap (example costs: [4.72€ in single-unit quantities](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology/ATSAME53J20A-AU?qs=sGAEpiMZZMuoKKEcg8mMKJ29ob8kKavQZ8U%2Fg6eW%252BjNpK3wx9Q4JWw%3D%3D)); but compared to the cost and complexity of an extra superhet stage, or even better resonant filters at 455 kHz, not actually!

Once you've got these digital samples, you can do *any* filtering you'd do in analog domain, but digitally, i.e. without component variations, without temperature dependency, without needing to hand-tune passive components until things are "just right"...

You can either do that on the microcontroller itself (given it's fast enough to do the computation), or you could off-load the processing to an application processor (e.g. the CPU in your laptop, or the CPU in your Raspberry Pi, although the first generations of RPis are really terrible computation platforms), e.g. by sending the samples over USB.

A realistic approach here would be to let the firmware:

- Get the samples from the ADC into a buffer using DMA,
- run a relatively relaxed half-band filter²
- which *decimates* (i.e. throws away \$N-1\$ of \$N\$ samples) by a decimation factor \$N=2\$
- and offers the remaining half-ADC-sample-rate sample stream via Full-Speed USB2 (i.e. 12 Mbit/s) to a PC,

where the PC then

- further filters and decimates down to say, 24 kHz containing the signal of interest,
- then uses your favourite frequency recovery (e.g. a PLL, depends on the kind of RF signal you're dealing with!) to home in very exactly on the signal of interest, so the analog side (oscillators, filters) doesn't have to be that frequency-exact
- further filters down to an arbitrary, adjustable bandwidth on the fly,
- applies whatever signal processing is relevant for your signal of interest (AM demod? FM demod? DRM demod? A PSK receiver? FreeDV demod? …) and generates the relevant output.

For the PC side of things, do have a look at [GNU Radio](https://gnuradio.org), it's meant to be a builder toolkit for *exactly* such signal processing chains.

---

¹ The minimum sampling rate necessary to unambigously represent a <5 kHz wide signal is 10 kHz; if your sample rate \$f_s\$ is larger than that, you're oversampling by a factor \$k=\frac{f_s}{10\,\text{kHz}}\$.

² When actually using 800 kSamples/s, 455 kHz would be aliased to 345 kHz, so you'd use a half-band high-pass filter, very possibly a CIC, which avoids having to do any multiplications, only additions and sign inversions, so you can keep working on the fixed-point numbers your ADC gives you without potentially getting into arithmetic trouble; it's computationally usually advantageous to do that.

Comment: I love your response, great work explaining DSP filters! I need that 2.5kHz or thereabouts (2.4kHz-2.7kHz) 3db bandwidth for getting SSB in a amateur radio transciever that I'm designing. I can build a McCoy filter with 4 crystals, but that takes a lot of resonators to find the two pairs needed. I know about DSP, but  the level of performance needed is not that strict to require it, plus the computer stuff would take up tons of space on board.

Comment: Well, as you can guess, for me, doing things in DSP is both easier and better than doing it in analog – in fact, if this is only about SSB, and your second stage filtering would only give you another ca 30 dB of suppression (judging by the little amplitude response plot from the datasheet), then you could work with a lot less oversampling – a \$k=16\$ oversampling would probably do, i.e. 160 kS/s; and a lot smaller MCUs might really do that out of the box; even with the large MCU my answer recommends, you'd actually have a non-trivial time making your analog filtering more compact than that,

Comment: but it'd be possible with small SMA components. Doing this on an MCU would be super handy, since it'd only take a single input to switch the software between LSB / USB, and you could have pre-computed filters in software for different bandwidths, which you can also switch at will, without any additional components required :) 160 kS/s is low enough for debugging to simply happen through your MCU spitting out the raw samples (without any DSP) on a few test pads :)

Comment: You are right, DSP seems to be the right answer. Sadly, I am currently unable to buy new components due to the epidemiological situation (not even online). I only have Attiny48, Attiny13A and a raspberry pi zero w. I would really like to know is it possible to work with the filters I mentioned.

Comment: @thegamebusterpl mouser, digikey AND farnell are still in full operation; it's pretty easy to order components right now.

Comment: I know, but I was forbidden by my dad from buying "unnecessary" things, due to a real possibility of job loss due to the epidemiological situation we are facing. What bandwidth do you think I will get when I connect these two 4kHz filters in series? Can I use the devices mentioned in my previous comment to do the DSP?

Comment: I answered that already. I don't know, it's impossible to say, and sudden "dad restrictions" make your question impossible to properly answer. If you have any restrictions – like no components that can't be exported to your country – then state them clearly in the question. Thank you!

Comment: I misunderstood you before, sorry. I thought you meant that getting an exact 2.5kHz bandwidth was almost impossible but didn't say anything about getting bandwidths in the range of 2.4kHz to 2.7kHz, sorry, my bad. That dad restriction came into effect a few hours ago, that is why it is not mentioned. I'm from Poland so there is not much of an issue getting even fancy IC's, the post office still delivers even during this plague.